# How to replace some letters in a copybook

Tags: cobol

Looking to replace the beginning letters of this copybook from "O-" to "IT-". Would anyone know how to do this.

```
FD INPUT-TRANSACTION-FILE                 
      RECORDING MODE IS F.                 
 01 ITRANS-RECORD.                         
 05  O-ACCOUNT-ID        PIC X(6).        
 05  O-FIRST-NAME        PIC X(15).       
 05  O-SURNAME           PIC X(20).       
 05  O-SALARY            PIC 9(6)V99.     
 05  O-TEMP REDEFINES O-SALARY PIC X(7).
```

When I call the copybook in my program I want to replace the "O" to "IT". I believe you can use REPLACING but I cannot seem to get it to work

Comment: This question has no accepted answer yet, please check those and either mark one as "works for me" or add comments on those if there's something unclear/missing.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the compiler in use (which you did not specify) but "in COBOL" you have a `LEADING` phrase for the `REPLACING` clause:

```
COPY FDITF REPLACING LEADING ==O-== BY ==IT-==.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are building the copy inside your program.
In that case, you can call them whatever you like, so just change them from 'O' to 'IT' manually.

If the copy (say we call it 'ITRANS') is outside the program,
you need to add to the copy a colon (`:`) before and after the letters to change:

```
FD INPUT-TRANSACTION-FILE                 
   RECORDING MODE IS F.                 
01 ITRANS-RECORD. 
   COPY 'ITRANS' REPLACING ==:O:== BY ==IT==.
```

Where the file copy 'ITRANS' is in the copy library.

```
05  :O:-ACCOUNT-ID        PIC X(6).        
05  :O:-FIRST-NAME        PIC X(15).       
05  :O:-SURNAME           PIC X(20).       
05  :O:-SALARY            PIC 9(6)V99.     
05  :O:-TEMP REDEFINES :O:-SALARY PIC X(7).
```

[IBM DOC - COPY statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/4.2?topic=statements-copy-statement)

Comment: Just to add: This technique is quite common used, it has the benefit that it works on all compilers I've seen (those that don't or don't correctly support `LEADING`, too). Its only downside: you have to adjust the copybook to use one of `:O:` or `'O'` and always have to use the `REPLACING` phrase. In general that's a good addition and another approach to the problem.